# Figure photography - where to share photos?

Tags: models, sharing

Our photography group recently held a figure photography session, with a nude model. We want to share our photos, but don't want to fall foul of strict site rules regarding nudity. Normally I'd use Picasa, but after trawling through their FAQ I found that they [explicitly forbid nudity](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=39524). Where's the best place to share (tasteful) nude shots?

Comment: Modelmayhem.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[photo.net](http://photo.net) allows them in public galleries. There are a lot of good pros there that show excellent work in all categories, including nudes.

There paying and free memberships. The free membership limits the gallery size and number of uploads.

Answer (score 13):

[Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) allows nudes as long as you change the image's "safety level" so kiddos and people at work don't get them popping up on a search; you're perfectly within the ToS. You can also make groups and galleries private if you'd rather limit who can see the photos and/or comment on them...

Answer (score 9):

You're allowed to host them on SmugMug as long as it's a non-public gallery (Note: I am affiliated w/said site :))

Answer (score 6):

- DeviantArt
- Flickr
- ModelMayhem
- 1x
- 500px
- jpgmag
- (.com to all the    above)
- eroticsignature.ning.com

Answer (score 4):

In addition to SmugMug being a great host they also are involved with DGrin which has a Go Figure Forum that is a good place to get comments that are constructive.

You also can try SmugMug for a 14 day trial if you want.

Comment: is this allowed? disclosure of affiliation with a suggested website seems reasonable, but coupons seems to stretch into propaganda realm, no? It's very nice to offer discounts, but sort of..."wrong"?

Comment: I have removed the link.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a very high quality gallery site, where artistic nudes are very appreciated, 1x.com is a great option. Warning: their standards are SUpER high!

Comment: But 1x isn't a photo sharing site, you have to actually submit and be accepted (unless that has changed), which is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 3):

I have a friend who switched from Flickr to DeviantArt after shooting at a fetish photography workshop. DeviantArt allows nude images, but requires the viewers to have an account so they can change their settings to view adult-rated material. (This works even when both the poster and the viewer have free accounts only).

This friend then stayed with DeviantArt for all kinds of photography and stopped using Flickr, because he said that on DeviantArt, there is a higher chance of random people seeing his pictures and offering constructive critique. So I suppose it can be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DeviantArt being a good option for sharing your pictures (although I'm personally tired of seeing  mostly nude photos there). The good thing with it is that the settings are personal for each user, that is you can allow nudity and mature contents pictures to appear on your page, or you can choose to hide them. Thus a lot of people can see your image if they have the proper settings, even if like me, their primary interest is not nude photos. I sometimes find photos that I like on my main page, although I would never search for nude photos on my own.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally I'd use Picasa, but after trawling through their FAQ I found
>   that they explicitly forbid nudity.

I had the same problem on Google+. Then I decided to create a photo blog on [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/):
https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/nsfw

Here's a sample created by a professional photographer, Andre Brito:
http://nude-abrito.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.bitpine.com love it! but these are other alternatives :

```
Bitpine
DeviantArt
Flickr
ModelMayhem
1x
500px
```

there are plenty out there google can help too :)

Answer (score -1):

The best website I recommend is http://www.imageshot.eu. You can create private or public albums and classified by categories, this great. greetings

Comment: Why is that? Are you affiliated with this site?

Comment: Why do you recommend it over other sites?  And what is its policy on nudity?

Comment: They definitely allow nudes, it's basically a post your own porn site... Technically, though, it answers the question.